# Query to get all users activity since last login

Tags: mysql

I want to create a query to get back **all users**, their **last login date** and how many questions they have answered since their last login.

I have the following query that does what I am looking for but with an individual user instead of all users.

```
SELECT l.user_id, 
   Count(*) attemptsSinceLastLogin 
FROM   production.score s 
   JOIN processedquestion pq 
     ON s.attempt_id = pq.attempt_id 
   JOIN login l 
     ON l.user_id = pq.user_id 
WHERE  l.user_id = 123
   AND s.selected_answer IS NOT NULL 
   AND pq.attempt_datetime > (SELECT Max(in_datetime) 
                              FROM   production.login 
                              WHERE  user_id = 123);
```

I also have this query that gets all users and their last log in date but it doesn't have how many questions they have answered.

```
SELECT user_id, 
   Max(in_datetime) 
FROM   production.login 
GROUP  BY user_id
```

I am having trouble using these two queries to try and come up with one that brings back the data I am looking for all in one go. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.user_id, 
       Count(*) attemptsSinceLastLogin 
FROM   production.score s 
   JOIN processedquestion pq 
     ON s.attempt_id = pq.attempt_id 
   JOIN login l 
     ON l.user_id = pq.user_id 
   JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
         Max(in_datetime) AS last_login
         FROM   production.login 
         GROUP  BY user_id) t
     ON l.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE  s.selected_answer IS NOT NULL 
       AND pq.attempt_datetime > t.last_login
GROUP BY l.user_id
```

Comment: nope, it just returns one column and the attempts number is way off

Comment: @nasoj1100 Sorry, I forgot the `GROUP BY` clause!